# QuickBooks QBFC explanation

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

- What is QBFC?
- How does it work in relation to posting invoices and purchase orders from a third party program to QuickBooks?
- Which QBFC version should I use with QuickBooks 2008?

Answer (score 12):

> I just want to know what a QBFC is

It's a COM library builds XML requests that QuickBooks can understand using objects. It also wraps some other QuickBooks COM components that allow you to send those XML requests to QuickBooks so that QuickBooks can process them.

> and how it works in relation to post invoices and Purchase Orders from a third party program to QuickBooks

Pretty much explained it above... there are 300+ pages of documentation about this in the QuickBooks SDK. If you need specific code examples, there are numerous examples included in the QuickBooks SDK.

> and which QBFC version should I use with QuickBooks 2008

Always use the latest version of QBFC. It's backward compatible with old versions of QuickBooks.

Comment: Maybe this was different 2 years ago, but I think it is actually a COM library, not .NET classes.

Comment: Hi could you please answer this https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D54R00007tXQZESA4/i-want-to-get-updated-refresh-token-and-access-token-however-when-i-call-oauth-2-api-to-get-the-updated-refresh-access-token-i-always-get-statuscodeerror-400-errorinvalidgrant

Comment: @eselk — COM doesn't necessarily preclude a .NET application.