# QuickBooks QBXML SDK releases and compatibility

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

Where can I find information about future releases of QBXML and outstanding issues? For instance, I would like to know if there are any changes that need to be made for the newest release of QuickBooks Desktop (2018).

According to [this link](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/0000_overview) QBXML 13.0 (Version 13.0.0.23) is the most recent version of the SDK. I have found release notes [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0100_essentials/quickbooks_desktop/release_notes), but it stops in 2015. Where can I go to review outstanding issues (e.g like QBWG-31698) and learn more about upcoming releases? We use QBFC 13.0 which is a COM class that manages QBXML messages (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259002/quickbooks-qbfc-explanation)).

Comment: Also i could not find anything on this, are there any SDK changes in QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise 18.0 ? From my work perspective i would like to know if paycheck generation with new SDK is possible. https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00004sugPACAY/how-we-can-create-employee-pay-cheques-using-qbfc?t=1517713726875

Comment: [Here is a question](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00004kavijCAA/qbfc-version) about minimum qbfc version that implies the only issue is field availability.